# Error When Clicking on User in People and Group

Tags: 2007

I'm getting this error when I click on a user in People and Group (MOSS 2007)

[image]

Has anybody experienced this? I've searched all over the internet but I can't find anyone who experienced the same issue.

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Your screenshot image is broken http://i.stack.imgur.com/70jw6.png

Comment: @Naim, works for me (DNS problem?)

Comment: Works fine for me, too.